# How to serialize in Django Rest Framework with a many to many field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model called `UserProfile` which is a `OneToOneField` to the default `User` model. I have a `Post` model which has `User` as `ManyToManyField`. I am unable to write a serializer for `Post` which includes `User` in responses.

My `UserProfile` model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

My `Post` model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

My `Post` serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserProfileSerializer(source='user.userprofile', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'title', 'users')
```

With above serializer I am getting the following error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `users` on serializer `WorkSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Work` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'userprofile'.
```

**EDIT**: I created another serializer `UserSerializerForPost` which is used in `PostSerializer`:

```
class UserSerializerForPost(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserProfileSerializer(source='userprofile')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user',)


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializerForPost(source='user', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'title', 'users')
```

Though this works, but I am getting `UserProfile` response in a dictionary of `user` as `users` list:

```
"users": [
  {
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      ...
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "id": 4,
      ...
    }
  }
]
```

But I want:

```
"users": [
  {
    "id": 2,
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    ...
    }
  }
],
```

Comment: That's because you are defining a `user` field in `UserSerializerForPost` serializer. Remove that field.

Comment: without defining it how can I provide `source`?

Comment: You just need to define a model in your Meta class.

Comment: How would more users create the same post ? Your model is really laid out like that ?

Comment: @Gocht if I just define a model, then it will serialise the `user`, not `UserProfile`

Comment: Define UserProfile as model

Comment: What shall I pass in `source`? Cos if I send `'user.userprofile'`, it throws the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Following solution worked for me and it did not even require creating `UserSerializerForPost`:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'title', 'users')

    def get_users(self, obj):
        response = []
        for _user in obj.user.all():
            user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(
                _user.userprofile,
                context={'request': self.context['request']})
            response.append(user_profile.data)
        return response
```

**EDIT**: Okay I found a even better approach than the above. First add a `get_user_profiles` to `Post`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_user_profiles(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.filter(user__post=self)
```

Then I updated my PostSerializer with:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserProfileSerializer(source='get_user_profiles', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'title', 'users')
```

This is way too cleaner version that earlier one.